# I have muiltiple polygons in a shapefile, and want to extract each polygon from a rasterfile and save as separate files

Tags: raster, shapefile, features, extract, rstudio

I have 80 polygons in a shapefile, and one complete raster file, I want to extract each polygon from a raster file and save it as a different raster files.

```
numPolygons <- length(shapefile)

uniquefield<-unique(shapefile$NAME)

for (i in 1:length(uniquefield)) {
  
 county_polygon <- shapefile[shapefile$NAME == uniquefield[i], ]
 
  county_cdl <- extract(rasterfile, county_polygon)
  
  output_filename <- paste0("county_cdl/", uniquefield[i], ".tif")
  
  writeRaster(county_cdl, file = output_filename, overwrite = TRUE)
}
```

I am getting errors.

Comment: Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘writeRaster’ for signature ‘"numeric", "character"’
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In .local(x, y, ...) :
  Transforming SpatialPolygons to the crs of the Raster
2: PROJ support is provided by the sf and terra packages among others